# Fullscreen image viewer from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created a `UICollectionView` with an image in each cell. I'm wondering how I can make a trigger action which will make the image fullscreen like in facebook, intagram or other apps. What is the best way in Swift to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the simplest solution in your case would be to put some code in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {     

}
```

in this function you already have selected indexPath.row so it should be easy to access the right image in your datasource. for example, if you are using array of images imagesArray, the right image would be imagesArray[indexPath.row].

after that you can create new UIViewController with UIImageView to show this image, or just UIImageView that will be shown over this collection view.

(I think you should also add UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDatasource to your current controller for this to work).

Comment: Well i want to get the behaviour like in facebook or other application where the image expand and is centered

Comment: Then you have to create/show new ViewController with UIImageView in it.

I answered similar question several minutes ago, maybe it could be useful for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914463/passing-an-image-when-taped-on-uicollectionview-to-a-detail-view-controller-in-s/32915031#32915031

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is that you can add an gesture detection on the image view inside the collection view.