# Passing an image when taped on uicollectionview to a detail view controller in swift

Tags: image, swift, view, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

Ive been at this for a while but cant seem to crack it in swift

I want a user to be able to select an image in uicollectionView and for that image to appear in a detailed view controller, i can do this quite easily with a peice of text,
and i can do this when there is a static array of images preloaded. but i cant seem to get anywhere with a collectionview which is loaded with images from a camera.

I understand i need to use

```
override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {
  }
```

and this function to isolated selected cell.

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  }
```

I do have these outlets
      @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

```
  var images = [UIImage]()
```

image picker stores all images to this array by

```
  images.insert(newImage, atIndex: 0)
```

when the array would be passed to the detailviewcontroller, i understand that would have to be copied into another local array and then how would i get the current image that was highlighted to be shown first, perhaps using indexPath.Row

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using segues, and actually I don't quite understand what your problem is, but I'll try to show you how it could be achieved.

First of all, you have an array with images, so I believe your image should be accessed as images[indexPath.row]

let's suppose that you already have UIViewController class with UIImageView in it.
if so, you can write something like that:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myVC = MyViewController()
    myVC.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
    self.presentViewController(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

for modal or

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myVC = MyViewController()
    myVC.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
}
```

if you want to show it as navigational.

I believe that with segues it's basically the same but I think you have to use func prepareForSegue for, you know, preparing the segue (func performSegueWithIdentifier will just perform it). In prepareForSegue you should check identifier of your segue

```
if segue.identifier == "myIdentifier" {
  //your code here
}
```

and if this identifier is right, put your commands to your myVC there.

Comment: Thanks i am still quite lost, heres what i tried,      override func    prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if (segue.identifier == "myIdentifier") {
       let mVC = segue.destinationViewController as! viewtwo

    performSegueWithIdentifier("myIdentifier", sender: self)
      
 }
 
 }
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,     didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let myVC = viewtwo()
   myVC.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
 
 
 }

Comment: and this is view two class viewtwo : UIViewController {
 
 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  
  
  
  var imageView: UIImage!
  
  
  
  
  
  
 }

Comment: sorry i dont know how to edit my comments so they are easier to see

Comment: you need to use didSelect..., not didDeselect (it's easy to confuse them)